# Is it possible to block a slider from being used after the handle gets released

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm trying to implement a slider in my site where users can give a rating. I'd like to insert that rating in my database after they release the handle so they can only rate once. Does anyone know how this is possible. I did some research but I don't seem to find anything. Any help is welcome aswell sites with more information on this.

Comment: Need more detail. are you using HTML range slider or any plugin?

Comment: Yes, a HTML slider. I'm sorry. I can't add any code yet since I'm new to this forum.

Comment: If its HTML slider, you can disable that on **onchange** event. That means once the value is changed, that will be disabled. ex <input type="range" disabled>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would initially set the slider up to its `input` and `change` events and then, in the `change` event handler, you would disconnect the `input` handler (because if no more input is processed, the value cannot change). The actual value to go in your database would come from an output placeholder.

You can even add a little CSS transition to remove the slider after the rating has been locked in.

After the UI has been configured, you'll need a way to prevent users from reloading the page and voting again and that can be done in several ways, but I would suggest a simple (but not foolproof) way, using `localStorgage`. You would set a "flag" in `localStorage` that indicates that a vote has been cast and as the page initially loads up, you would check `localStorage` to see if that flag had been previously set.

**NOTE**: `localStorage` doesn't work here in the Stack Overflow Code Snippet environment, but you can see it working at **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpa4oc98/)**.

Here's an example:

```js
let out = document.getElementById("output");
let slider = document.getElementById("rating"); 

// Check to see if the user has already voted
if(localStorage.getItem("vote") === "true"){
  // User has voted
  out.textContent = "Your vote has already been cast.";
  slider.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide the slider
} else {
  // User has not voted

  // Set up event listener that records value
  slider.addEventListener("input", rate);

  // Set up event listener that disconnects first event listener
  slider.addEventListener("change", disconnect);
}

function rate(){
  out.textContent = this.value;
}

function disconnect(){
  this.removeEventListener("input", rate);  // Disconnect the input event handler
  this.classList.add("hidden");  // Hide the slider at this point
  
  // Update your database with the rating stored in the output
  console.log("Your rating of: " + out.textContent + " has been recorded!");
  
  // Set the "flag" 
  localStorage.setItem("vote", "true");
}
```

```css
#rating { opacity:1; transition:all 1s; width:15em; }
#rating.hidden { opacity:0; width:0; }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="rating" min="0" max="10">
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: @Pushpanathan K Please stop trying to edit my answer. I like it the way it is, that's why I've rejected your edit twice.

Comment: @Pushpanathan K Why do you persist in attempting to edit my answer to function fundamentally differently than I want it to? Stop!

Comment: @PushpanathanK Please use your edit privilege wisely and correctly. It is not to change the code solutions provided in answers so that they function the way you want them to. It is for making answers more clear and fixing typos, but ***never*** to alter the meaning or purpose of an answer. If you have an idea about how the solution should work, post your own answer.

Comment: Hey man. Sorry for the late answer but thanks alot. This is exactly what I wanted! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie for visitors with 'rated' set to 'true' when the user votes. Check for the cookie before saving the vote. That is probably your simplest method, but some scenarios will still let users vote multiple times. They include:

- users that jump to another browser / incognito session
- users that access the site from multiple devices, e.g. mobile, desktop
- users that purge or block cookies won't be controlled

Overall, there is no fool proof method to prevent multiple ratings. The closest might be by forcing the users to login before voting, so you know who they are and can control what they do.